# Is didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called when app opens from push notification

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appdelegate

I have killed the app from background. After killing the app, I send one push notification. I have two doubts on the `AppDelegate` functions that will be called :
**1**. Will `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` be called ?
**2**. If yes, the will `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` be called first or `didReceiveRemoteNotification` be called first ?

I am not able to test this scenario as this cannot be debugged, the fact that app opens from push notification.

Answer (score 6):

**if your application is in background mode** than `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is never called only `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is called

And **if your application is killed than** only `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method is called `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method is never called.

Comment: Well when app is killed, then the code in didReceiveRemoteNotification is executing on receiving push notification.

Comment: And if didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called, how can I identify that pp is opened from push notification ?

Answer (score 2):

> I have killed the app from background.

I guess you're trying to say that you've removed the app from tray. If so,

1. Yes, in that case it will get call.
2. `didReceiveRemoteNotification` will not call at this time. It will only get call if your app is running in background.

Comment: Well when app is killed, then the code in didReceiveRemoteNotification is executing on receiving push notification.

Comment: And if didReceiveRemoteNotification is not called, how can I identify that pp is opened from push notification ?

Comment: Yes, you can check for it like this, `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if (launchOptions != nil) {
         // Launched from push notification
         NSDictionary *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

    }
}`